# Find overlapping date ranges in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, overlap, date-range

Is this correct?

```
SELECT * 
FROM   contract 
JOIN   team USING (name_team) 
JOIN   player USING(name_player) 
WHERE  name_team = ? 
AND    DATE_PART('YEAR',date_join)>= ? 
AND    DATE_PART('YEAR',date_leave)<= ?
```

My table `contract` has the player name, team name and the dates when he joined and left the club.
I want to make a function listing all players that were on the team in specific years.
The above query doesn't seem to be working ...

Comment: there is no error.. the results are not correct..

Comment: Then you don't have data for the criteria you've specified

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not use between without the date part thing:

```
WHERE datefield BETWEEN '2009-10-10 00:00:00' AND '2009-10-11 00:00:00'
```

or something like that?

Comment: UPPER CASE IS NOT REQUIRED BY THE SQL SPEC WHY WAS MY ANSWER EDITED? See, upper case isn't necessarily easier to read. Joshua, please don't edit my answer because it offends your upper case sensibilities.

Comment: For those learning, I think it is much easier to read because it extremely clearly distinguishes SQL keywords from developer editable object names.

Comment: I think that the OP was asking how to compare date ranges. Isn't this condition to check whether a datetime is in a time range?

Answer (score 105):

The [currently accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4481773/939860) does not answer the question. And it is wrong in principle. `a BETWEEN x AND y` translates to:

```sql
a >= x AND a <= y
```

*Including* the upper bound, while people typically need to *exclude* it:

```sql
a >= x AND a < y
```

With *dates* you can easily adjust. For the year 2009 use '2009-12-31' as upper bound.
But it's not as simple with *timestamps* which allow fractional digits. Modern Postgres versions use an 8-byte integer internally to store up to 6 fractional seconds (µs resolution). Knowing this we *could* still make it work, but that's not intuitive and depends on an implementation detail. Bad idea.

Moreover, `a BETWEEN x AND y` does not find overlapping ranges. We need:

```sql
b >= x AND a < y
```

And players that *never left* are not considered, yet.

#### Proper answer

Assuming the year ***`2009`***, I'll rephrase the question without changing its meaning:

*"Find all players of a given team who joined before 2010 and did not leave before 2009."*

***Basic query:***

```sql
SELECT p.*
FROM   team     t
JOIN   contract c USING (name_team) 
JOIN   player   p USING (name_player) 
WHERE  t.name_team = ? 
AND    c.date_join  <  date '2010-01-01'
AND    c.date_leave >= date '2009-01-01';
```

But there is more:

If referential integrity is enforced with FK constraints, the table `team` itself is just noise in the query and can be removed.

While the same player can leave and rejoin the same team, we also need to fold possible duplicates, for instance with `DISTINCT`.

And we *may* need to provide for a special case: players that never left. Assuming those players have NULL in `date_leave`.

*"A player that is not known to have left is assumed to be playing for the team to this day."*

***Refined query:***

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT p.* 
FROM   contract c
JOIN   player   p USING (name_player) 
WHERE  c.name_team = ? 
AND    c.date_join  <  date '2010-01-01'
AND   (c.date_leave >= date '2009-01-01' OR c.date_leave IS NULL);
```

[Operator precedence](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-PRECEDENCE) works against us, `AND` binds before `OR`. We need parentheses.

Related answer with optimized `DISTINCT` (if duplicates are common):

- [Many to Many Table - Performance is bad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46301784/many-to-many-table-performance-is-bad/46303473#46303473)

Typically, *names* of natural persons aren't unique and a surrogate primary key is used. But, obviously, `name_player` is the primary key of `player`. If all you need is player names we don't need the table `player` in the query, either:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT name_player 
FROM   contract
WHERE  name_team = ? 
AND    date_join  <  date '2010-01-01'
AND   (date_leave >= date '2009-01-01' OR date_leave IS NULL);
```

#### SQL `OVERLAPS` operator

[The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TABLE)

> `OVERLAPS` automatically takes the earlier value of the pair as the
> start. Each time period is considered to represent the half-open
> interval `start <= time < end`, unless `start` and `end` are equal in
> which case it represents that single time instant.

To take care of potential `NULL` values, [`COALESCE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-COALESCE-NVL-IFNULL) seems easiest:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT name_player 
FROM   contract
WHERE  name_team = ? 
AND    (date_join, COALESCE(date_leave, CURRENT_DATE)) OVERLAPS
       (date '2009-01-01', date '2010-01-01');  -- upper bound excluded
```

#### Range type with index support

In Postgres **9.2 or later** you can also operate with actual [**range types**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html):

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT name_player 
FROM   contract
WHERE  name_team = ? 
AND    daterange(date_join, date_leave) &&
       daterange '[2009-01-01,2010-01-01)';  -- upper bound excluded
```

Range types add some overhead and occupy more space. 2  x `date` = 8 bytes; 1 x `daterange` = 14 bytes on disk or 17 bytes in RAM. But in combination with the [**overlap operator `&&`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-range.html) the query can be supported with a GiST index.

Also, no need to special-case NULL values. NULL means "open range" in a range type - exactly what we need. The table definition doesn't even have to change: we can create the range type on the fly - and support the query with a matching expression index:

```sql
CREATE INDEX mv_stock_dr_idx ON mv_stock USING gist (daterange(date_join, date_leave));
```

Related:

- [Average stock history table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25247911/average-stock-history-table/25252274#25252274)

Comment: I'll up vote you but you know no one is ever gonna see this being it's 2+ years old right? :)

Comment: @ScottMarlowe: Thanks. Well, an edit to your answer pulled this one into the "active" list and I couldn't refrain from correcting what seemed incorrect to me. SO is the place to act out on one's OCD and get upvotes for it, isn't it? :)

Comment: Agreed. And yeah overlaps is the better answer by far.

Comment: @Erwin Brandstetter: I also get the same problem with 'between' . My DB function also not working correctly with 'between'.  Your explanation is perfect. Upvote it.

Comment: This is the most complete and correct answer, because other answers does not resolve the case when the player joined the team BEFORE and left if AFTER the requested period of time.

Comment: @ScottMarlowe, I saw it just now.