# Optimize BETWEEN date statement

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing, between, postgresql-performance

I need help optimizing a Postgres query which uses the `BETWEEN` clause with a `timestamp` field.

I have 2 tables:

```
ONE(int id_one(PK), datetime cut_time, int f1 ...)
```

containing about 3394 rows

```
TWO(int id_two(PK), int id_one(FK), int f2 ...)
```

containing about 4000000 rows

There are btree indexes on both PKs `id_one` and `id_two`, on the FK `id_one` and `cut_time`.

I want to perform a query like:

```
select o.id_one, Date(o.cut_time), o.f1, t.f2 
from one o
inner join two t ON (o.id_one = t.id_one)
where o.cut_time between '2013-01-01' and '2013-01-31';
```

This query retrieves about 1.700.000 rows in about 7 seconds.

Below the explain analyze report is reported:

```
Merge Join  (cost=20000000003.53..20000197562.38 rows=1680916 width=24) (actual time=0.017..741.718 rows=1692345 loops=1)"
  Merge Cond: (c.coilid = hf.coilid)
  ->  Index Scan using pk_coils on coils c  (cost=10000000000.00..10000000382.13 rows=1420 width=16) (actual time=0.008..4.539 rows=1404 loops=1)
        Filter: ((cut_time >= '2013-01-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (cut_time <= '2013-01-31 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone))
        Rows Removed by Filter: 1990
  ->  Index Scan using idx_fk_lf_data on hf_data hf  (cost=10000000000.00..10000166145.90 rows=4017625 width=16) (actual time=0.003..392.535 rows=1963386 loops=1)
Total runtime: 768.473 ms
```

The index on the timestamp column isn't used. How to optimize this query?

Comment: Have you been disabling planner options? The costs of cost=10000000000.00 look awfully suspicious.

Comment: How I can set the defalut value for the planner options?

Comment: I was thinking you'd maybe changed one or more of these to off: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/runtime-config-query.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-QUERY-ENABLE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The query executes in less than one second. The other 6+ seconds are spent on traffic between server and client.

Comment: Thank you Neto, ok the effective time of query execution is less than one second. I will see this latency in the traffic between client and server when I will develop my solution too?

Comment: @Nko Sure. Probably worse. Do you need 1.7 million rows?

Comment: @Nko...Neto is right. You aren't going to gain a lot optimizing the date clause at this point. The number of records you are retrieving is the main issue.

Comment: OK thanks, this was just my first approach on this kind of data, surely I need to aggregate this retrieved data, minimizing in this way the total time of execution. Thanks

Answer (score 8):

#### Proper DDL script

A proper setup could look like this:

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=bc511c65efe2491ab4868823326a035a)*
<sub>[Old sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/39f06/1)</sub>

More about this fiddle further down.
Assuming data type [`timestamp`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html) for the column `datetime`.

#### Incorrect query

`BETWEEN` is almost always **wrong** on principal with `timestamp` columns. See:

- [Find overlapping date ranges in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4480715/find-overlapping-date-ranges-in-postgresql/15305292#15305292)

In *your query*:

```sql
SELECT o.one_id, date(o.cut_time), o.f1, t.f2 
FROM   one o
JOIN   two t USING (one_id)
WHERE  o.cut_time BETWEEN '2013-01-01' AND '2013-01-31';
```

... the string constants '2013-01-01' and '2013-01-31' are coerced to the timestamps '2013-01-01 00:00' and '2013-01-31 00:00'. This excludes most of Jan. 31. The timestamp '2013-01-31 12:00' would not qualify, which is most certainly **wrong**.
If you'd use '2013-02-01' as upper bound instead, it would include '2013-02-01 00:00'. Still wrong.

To get *all timestamps of "January 2013"* it **needs to be**:

```
SELECT o.one_id, date(o.cut_time), o.f1, t.f2 
FROM   one o
JOIN   two t USING (one_id)
WHERE  o.cut_time >= '2013-01-01'
AND    o.cut_time <  '2013-02-01';
```

**Exclude the upper bound.**

#### Optimize query

It's probably pointless to retrieve 1.7 million rows. Aggregate *before* you retrieve the result.

Since table `two` is so much bigger, it's crucial how many rows you get from there. When retrieving more than ~ 5 %, a plain **index on `two.one_id` will typically not be used**, because it is faster to scan the table sequentially right away.

Your table statistics are outdated, or you have messed with cost constants and other parameters (which you obviously have, see below) to force Postgres into using the index anyway.

The only chance I would see for an index on `two` is a **covering index**:

```
CREATE INDEX two_one_id_f2 ON two(one_id, f2);
```

This way, Postgres could read from the index directly, if some preconditions are met. Might be a bit faster, not much. Didn't test.

#### Strange numbers in `EXPLAIN` output

As to your strange numbers in your `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`. The [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=bc511c65efe2491ab4868823326a035a) should explain it.

Seems like you had these debug settings:

```
SET enable_seqscan = off;
SET enable_indexscan = off;
SET enable_bitmapscan = off;
```

**All of them should be `on`** (default setting), except for debugging. Else it cripples performance! Check with:

```
SELECT * FROM pg_settings WHERE name ~~ 'enable%';
```

Comment: Good catch on the `BETWEEN` with the `timestsamp` and really nice, informative post. I learned something :)

Comment: Thanks Erwin for the covering index tip. Sorry, I've missed to give you the information that I'm using Postgresql 9.2.