# Join across multiple tables with partial counts

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, aggregate-functions

Each `company`, has products and each `product` has entries in `detail1`, `detail2`, `detail3` table.

```
**Table Company**
cid |   cname   
-----+-----------
100 | Company 1
101 | Company 2

**Table Product**
pid  | cid |   dname   
------+-----+-----------
1000 | 100 | Product A
2000 | 101 | Product B

**Table detail1**
pid  | state |          datetime          
------+-------+----------------------------
1000 | A     | 2013-06-03 11:49:49.224992
1000 | B     | 2013-06-03 11:49:49.226124
1000 | B     | 2013-06-03 11:49:49.228573
1000 | B     | 2013-06-03 11:49:49.23136
1000 | A     | 2013-06-03 11:49:49.233897
2000 | A     | 2013-06-03 11:49:49.243572
2000 | B     | 2013-06-03 11:49:49.245899

**Table detail2**
pid  | type |          datetime          
------+------+----------------------------
1000 | T1   | 2013-06-03 11:49:49.257978
1000 | T1   | 2013-06-03 11:49:49.258865
1000 | T1   | 2013-06-03 11:49:49.261212
1000 | T1   | 2013-06-03 11:49:49.263515
2000 | T1   | 2013-06-03 11:49:49.270654

**Table detail3**
pid  | quality |          datetime          
------+---------+----------------------------
1000 | Q1      | 2013-06-03 11:49:49.280894
1000 | Q1      | 2013-06-03 11:49:49.281786
1000 | Q1      | 2013-06-03 11:49:49.284011
2000 | Q1      | 2013-06-03 11:49:49.287797
2000 | Q1      | 2013-06-03 11:49:49.288629
2000 | Q1      | 2013-06-03 11:49:49.289587
```

I am looking for a query that would return data as follows:

```
CompanyID  CompanyName  detail1.StateA  detail1.stateB  count(detail2) count(detail3)
---------- ------------ --------------- --------------- -------------- ---------------
100        Company 1         2               3                4             3
101        Company 2         1               1                1             2
```

I might further restrict the result based on `datetime` constraint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT c.cid
      ,c.cname
      ,sum(d1.d1_a_ct) AS d1_a_ct
      ,sum(d1.d1_b_ct) AS d1_b_ct
      ,sum(d2.d2_ct)   AS d2_ct
      ,sum(d3.d3_ct)   AS d3_ct
FROM   company c
LEFT   JOIN product p USING (cid)
LEFT   JOIN (
   SELECT pid, count(state = 'A' OR NULL) AS d1_a_ct
              ,count(state = 'B' OR NULL) AS d1_b_ct
   FROM   detail1
   -- WHERE datetime >= '2013-06-03 11:45:00'
   -- AND   datetime <  '2013-06-05 15:00:00'
   GROUP  BY pid
   ) d1   USING (pid)
LEFT   JOIN (
   SELECT pid, count(*) AS d2_ct
   FROM   detail2
   GROUP  BY pid
   ) d2   USING (pid)
LEFT   JOIN (
   SELECT pid, count(*) AS d3_ct
   FROM   detail3
   GROUP  BY pid
   ) d3   USING (pid);
GROUP BY  c.cid, c.cname;
```

It is important to avoid a "proxy cross join" in a situation like this.
If you join to multiple n-tables (detail1, detail2, ...) and each can have multiple related rows, the rows would multiply each other.
To avoid the problem first aggregate the detail-tables so there is only **1** row per product. Then it's no problem to join all of them at once to the respective product.

More explanation in this related answer:
[Two SQL LEFT JOINS produce incorrect result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12464037/two-sql-left-joins-produce-incorrect-result)

I also use `LEFT JOIN`, even though you wrote that "`each` product has entries in ..". Can't hurt. Else, if there wouldn't be related rows in one of the detail-tables, you'd lose the whole company from the result.

I did the same for products, so you even get companies without any products at all.

Here is an explanation on how the partial counts with `count(state = 'A' OR NULL)` work:
[Compute percents from SUM() in the same SELECT sql query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15644713/compute-percents-from-sum-in-the-same-select-sql-query/15650897#15650897)

It is simple to further restrict on the `datetime` column. I added a commented `WHERE` clause. Note the use of `>=` and `<` to avoid [a common mistake with `timestamp` ranges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16039649/optimize-postgresql-between-date-statement/16048214#16048214).

Comment: Thank you for your response and explanation. It is really helpful. Yes, in my example the detail(s) table have entry but in reality the entries may or may not be present. I was looking for something to work with. I will try out your query. Thanks again.

Comment: @aquitted-mind: I also added a bit for the `datetime` restriction.