# Sustract two queries from same table

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions, subtraction

Let's say I have 2 tables:
table `device` is a set of measuring devices, table `data` is a set of values of different types measured by the devices.

```
Table data = (no, id,value_type,value, dayhour) no is PK, id refer to table device
Table device = (id, name) id is PK
```

I currently have a query that will obtain the sum of all values of a specific `value_type` generated by an `id` on a specific date, something like:

```
SELECT SUM(cast(a.value as int)),b.name FROM data a INNER JOIN device b
ON a.id=b.id 
AND a.id=1
AND a.value_type=2
AND date(a.dayhour)='2015-12-12'
GROUP BY b.name
```

The query works without problems. Now I want to be able to subtract the sum  of different value types. What I'm currently doing is two queries, one for obtaining the sum for `value_type` 2 and another for the sum for `value_type` 3 and then doing the subtraction at an upper layer process.

However, I would like to do this from a single query, something like a query that will retrieve one column with the sum of `value_type` 2, another with the sum of `value_type` 3 and a third one with the subtraction of these 2 columns.

Comment: Please provide proper table definitions: what you get with `\d tbl` in psql or original `CREATE TABLE` scripts. Also, as *always*: your version of Postgres.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sql
SELECT b.name, a.*, a.sum2 - a.sum3 AS diff
FROM  (
    SELECT id
         , sum(value::int) FILTER (WHERE value_type = 2) AS sum2
         , sum(value::int) FILTER (WHERE value_type = 3) AS sum3
    FROM   data
    WHERE  id = 1
    AND    value_type IN (2, 3)
    AND    dayhour >= '2015-12-12'::timestamp
    AND    dayhour <  '2015-12-13'::timestamp
    GROUP  BY 1
    ) a
JOIN   device b USING (id);
```

Assuming `dayhour` is of data type `timestamp`.
The cast to `date` would disable basic indexes. Use [sargable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable) predicates like demonstrated instead. See:

- [Optimize BETWEEN date statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16039649/optimize-between-date-statement/16048214#16048214)

Use the aggregate `FILTER` clause for conditional aggregates (since Postgres 9.4). See:

- [Aggregate columns with additional (distinct) filters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27136251/aggregate-columns-with-additional-distinct-filters/27141193#27141193)

Why the cast `value::int`?
Aggregate first, then join to device. Cheaper.

Comment: Thanks!!!! This is exactly what I needed. I've been playing with CASE statement but didn't find the correct syntax