# Postgres jsonb array join

Tags: arrays, postgresql, aggregation, jsonb

I have a jsonb document in a table.  This document has an array of cameraIds in the document.  I am trying to join this data with the cameras table that is a normal table where cameraId is a column, and return unique rows from the table with the jsonb column (why I am using a group by in my query).

Any advice on how to optimize this query for performance would be greatly appreciated.

JSONB Col Example:

```
{
  "date": {
    "end": "2018-11-02T22:00:00.000Z", 
    "start": "2018-11-02T14:30:00.000Z"
  }, 
  "cameraIds": [100, 101], 
  "networkId": 5, 
  "filters": [], 
  "includeUnprocessed": true, 
  "reason": "some reason", 
  "vehicleFilter": { 
    "bodyInfo": "something", 
    "lpInfo": "something"
  }
}
```

Query:

```
select ssr.id,
                a.name                                               as user_name,
                ssr.start_date,
                ssr.end_date,
                ssr.created_at,
                ssr.payload -> 'filters'                       as pretty_filters,
                ssr.payload -> 'reason'                              as reason,
                ssr.payload -> 'includePlates'                as include_plates,
                ssr.payload -> 'vehicleFilter' -> 'bodyInfo'         as vbf,
                ssr.payload -> 'vehicleFilter' -> 'lpInfo' as lpInfo,
                array_agg(n.name) filter (where n.organization_id = ${orgId})  as network_names,
                array_agg(c.name) filter (where n.organization_id = ${orgId})  as camera_names
from
    ssr
    cross join jsonb_array_elements(ssr.payload -> 'cameraIds') camera_id
         inner join cameras as c on c.id = camera_id::int
         inner join networks as n on n.id = c.network_id
         inner join accounts as a on ssr.account_id = a.id
where n.organization_id = ${someId}
and ssr.created_at between ${startDate} and ${endDat}
group by 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
order BY ssr.created_at desc
    OFFSET 0
LIMIT 25;
```

Comment: You're saying the query is working exactly as expected but performance is bad and you want us to help optimising that?

Comment: For performance questions, please include the definitions of the involved tables and the indices on them as well as the query plan of your statement (`ANALYZE`).

Comment: Your existing query requires reading every `ssr.payload` column to work.  Since `ssr` has a `created_at` column, I suggest adding a table, `ssr_camera` with `ssr_id`, `camera_id`, and `created_at` as columns, and maintain it when you insert into `ssr` .  Join through the new `ssr_camera` table in your query.

Comment: So do you have your answer?

Answer (score 0):

Your query says:

```
where n.organization_id = ${someId}
```

But then the aggregate `FILTER` says:

```
where n.organization_id = ${orgId}
```

... which is a contradiction. The aggregated arrays would always be empty - except where `${orgId}` happens to be the same as `${someId}`, but then the `FILTER` clause is useless noise. IOW, the query doesn't seem to make sense as given.

The query *might* make sense after dropping the aggregate `FILTER` clauses:

```sql
SELECT s.id
     , a.name                                      AS user_name
     , s.start_date
     , s.end_date
     , s.created_at
     , s.payload ->> 'filters'                     AS pretty_filters
     , s.payload ->> 'reason'                      AS reason
     , s.payload ->> 'includePlates'               AS include_plates
     , s.payload -> 'vehicleFilter' ->> 'bodyInfo' AS vbf
     , s.payload -> 'vehicleFilter' ->> 'lpInfo'   AS lpInfo
     , cn.camera_names
     , cn.network_names
FROM   ssr      s
JOIN   accounts a ON a.id = s.account_id  -- assuming referential integrity
CROSS  JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT array_agg(c.name) AS camera_names   -- sort order?
        , array_agg(n.name) AS network_names  -- same order? distinct?
   FROM   jsonb_array_elements_text(ssr.payload -> 'cameraIds') i(camera_id)
   JOIN   cameras  c ON c.id = i.camera_id::int
   JOIN   networks n ON n.id = c.network_id
   WHERE  n.organization_id = ${orgId}
   ) cn
WHERE  s.created_at BETWEEN ${startDate} AND ${endDate}  -- ?
ORDER  BY s.created_at DESC NULLS LAST
LIMIT  25;
```

Key is the `LATERAL` subquery, which avoids duplication of rows from `ssr`, so we can also drop the outer `GROUP BY`. Should be considerably faster.

Also note `->>` instead of `->` and `jsonb_array_elements_text()`. See:

- [How to turn JSON array into Postgres array?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/54289/3684)

I left some question marks at more dubious spots in the query. Notably, `BETWEEN` is almost always the wrong tool for timestamps. See:

- [Subtract hours from the now() function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30894296/subtract-hours-from-the-now-function/30896121#30896121)