# How to apply time slices to an existing SQL query

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group, postgresql-9.1, date-range

I have a table with approx 8 million rows that I need time slice data from.
I'm using PostgreSQL 9.1.

I need to query this table for a sum of the max(start_time) associated 'data' values for each 'object_id' (given a list), on a per day basis.  (In other words, the closest record to the end of each day, for each object_id in a specific list).

Here's the basic table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE checks (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  object_id INTEGER,
  state INTEGER,
  start_time TIMESTAMP,
  data TEXT
);
```

`data` is a `TEXT` field, but has `numeric` values (I can't change this aspect, but can convert using casts).

And here's the query I'm working with so far:

```
WITH object_ids AS ( 
    SELECT object_id FROM objects WHERE object_id in (14845,12504,12451,12452)
),
records AS (
    SELECT
        data,
        start_time,
        MAX(start_time) OVER (PARTITION BY object_id)
    FROM checks
    WHERE
        object_id IN (SELECT object_id FROM object_ids) AND
        state = 0 AND
        start_time BETWEEN '2013-05-01 00:00:00' AND '2013-05-02 00:00:00'
)   
SELECT 
    SUM(data::bigint) 
FROM   
    records
WHERE 
    max = start_time
```

I'll run this query for each day of the month to give me a set of chart data points.

I would love to modify this query so I don't have to run separate queries per day, but one query to return a set of per day values

```
start_time          | sum
---------------------------
2013-05-01 00:00:00 | 39118
2013-05-02 00:00:00 | 98387
2013-05-03 00:00:00 | 8384
```

I've been researching time slice questions, and they are very helpful (I owe the fact that I'm using windowing functions to StackOverflow!), but I just can't make the leap to solving this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT day, sum(data) AS total_per_day
FROM  (
   SELECT DISTINCT ON (object_id, 1)
          start_time::date, data::numeric
   FROM   checks c
   WHERE  object_id in (14845,12504,12451,12452)
   AND    state = 0
   AND    start_time >= '2013-04-01'::date
   AND    start_time <  '2013-05-05'::date   -- any range of days
   ORDER  BY object_id, 1, c.start_time DESC -- seems redundant, see text
   ) x
GROUP BY  1
ORDER BY  1
```

This gives you one row day with a sum. I realize it's much like what [@Clodoaldo already posted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16430197/939860), but I demonstrate correct `DISTINCT ON` syntax, plus some other improvements and some necessary explanation.

- You can use `DISTINCT ON` to the the data-value per day. Should be simpler and faster than a window function:

  - [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)
- The `ORDER BY` clause has to agree with the `DISTINCT ON` expressions (details in the linked answer). That's the reason for:

  ```
  ORDER  BY 1, start_time::date, start_time DESC
  ```

  The second item would seem redundand, but is needed here.
- The get the `date` from a `timestamp`, just cast: `start_time::date`.
- Careful when you include `start_time::date` (which I optimized out) in the `SELECT` list. In `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY` output columns take precedence over input columns (as opposed to `WHERE` and `HAVING` where you can only reference input columns). You have to use a different alias for the output column or table-qualify the base column to refer to it: `c.start_time`
- With `timestamp` you practically always will want to exclude the upper border. Details in this related answer:

  - [Find overlapping date ranges in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4480715/find-overlapping-date-ranges-in-postgresql/15305292#15305292)

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  When I try the query out, I get an error: ERROR:  aggregates not allowed in GROUP BY clause - for the sum()

Comment: @AllanN: Ah, sorry. Only group by the first column, of course.

Comment: After testing this query out, it works quite well.  Performance is good as well, as the query plan is using the proper indexes.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
select
    "day", sum(data) "data"
from (
    select distinct (1, 2)
        object_id,
        date_trunc('day', start_time)::date "day",
        start_time,
        "data"
    from checks
    where
        object_id in (14845,12504,12451,12452)
        and state = 0
    order by 1, 2, 3 desc
) s
group by 1
order by 1
```