# PostgreSQL function with select returning one value

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql, sql-function

I have a table `years` (jan 1st of each ear). I want to create a function that takes each of those years and runs a query on another table to count the number of rows that belonging to that year. I tried to implement with pl/pgsql, using the code bellow, but I'm not getting it to work or finding any reference on the Internet.

```
CREATE or REPLACE FUNCTION func_test(in AAA date, OUT _result int) 
BEGIN
   SELECT SUM(st_length(geom)) as BBB
   FROM hist_line
   WHERE '2006-01-01' BETWEEN valid_from AND COALESCE(valid_to, '9999-12-31');
   RETURN _result BBB;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
CREATE or REPLACE FUNCTION func_test(date) 

select func_test('2009-01-01');
```

I'm not able to recover the content query inside the function as the output of the function.

Comment: So, do you use Oracle or Postgresql?

Comment: @ Guneli: i use Postgresql

Answer (score 15):

Your code has more than one issue, but main bug is wrongly using SELECT statement - what do you do has not sense. Embedded SQL in plpgsql has special clause "INTO targetvar":

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION func_test(in AAA date, OUT _result int)
AS $$
BEGIN
   SELECT SUM(st_length(geom)) INTO _result
      FROM hist_line
     WHERE AAA BETWEEN valid_from AND COALESCE(valid_to, '9999-12-31');
   RETURN;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

These one line functions should not be implemented in plpgsql. Just use SQL.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION func_test(in AAA date)
RETURNS int AS $$
   SELECT SUM(st_length(geom)) 
      FROM hist_line
     WHERE $1 BETWEEN valid_from AND COALESCE(valid_to, '9999-12-31');
$$ LANGUAGE sql;
```

Good source about PL/pgSQL is related [chapter](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/plpgsql.html)  in PostgreSQL documentation. Second source can be my [tutorial](http://postgres.cz/wiki/PL/pgSQL_%28en%29).

Answer (score 1):

What @Pavel said. Plus, according to your description, **you do not need a function at all**.

> I want to create a function that takes each of those years and runs a
>   query on another table to count the number of rows that belonging to that year.

"Belonging to a year" seems to mean "overlapping time range". Use a simple query with a [`JOIN`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-JOIN), a smart join condition and aggregation.

Assuming this table (missing in the question):

```
CREATE TABLE years (
  the_date date PRIMARY KEY
);
```

This query would do the job:

```
SELECT the_date, count(*) AS row_ct
FROM   years y
JOIN   other_table o ON (y.the_date, y.the_date + interval '1 year')
               OVERLAPS (o.valid_from, COALESCE(o.valid_to, 'infinity'))
GROUP  BY 1;
```

About the [`OVERLAPS`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TABLE) operator:

- [Find overlapping date ranges in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4480715/find-overlapping-date-ranges-in-postgresql/15305292#15305292)

[The manual about `'infinity'`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-DATETIME-SPECIAL-TABLE).