# Average stock history table

Tags: sql, postgresql, average, date-range, window-functions

I have a table that tracks changes in stocks through time for some stores and products. The value is the absolute stock, but we only insert a new row when a change in stock occurs. This design was to keep the table small, because it is expected to grow rapidly.

This is an example schema and some test data:

```
CREATE TABLE stocks (
  id serial NOT NULL,
  store_id integer NOT NULL,
  product_id integer NOT NULL,
  date date NOT NULL,
  value integer NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT stocks_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT stocks_store_id_product_id_date_key 
    UNIQUE (store_id, product_id, date)
);

insert into stocks(store_id, product_id, date, value) values
(1,10,'2013-01-05', 4),
(1,10,'2013-01-09', 7),
(1,10,'2013-01-11', 5),
(1,11,'2013-01-05', 8),
(2,10,'2013-01-04', 12),
(2,11,'2012-12-04', 23);
```

I need to be able to determine the average stock between a start and end date, per product and store, but my problem is that a simple avg() doesn't take into account that the stock remains the same between changes.

What I would like is something like this:

```
select s.store_id,  s.product_id , special_avg(s.value) 
from stocks s where s.date between '2013-01-01' and '2013-01-15'
group by s.store_id,  s.product_id
```

with the result being something like this:

```
store_id  product_id  avg
1         10          3.6666666667
1         11          5.8666666667
2         10          9.6
2         11          23
```

In order to use the SQL average function I would need to "propagate" forward in time the previous value for a store_id and product_id, until a new change occurs. Any ideas as how to achieve this?

Comment: How many rows does the table have now, and over what time period?

Comment: Please can you tell how exectly do you want to perform average. how you are getting all these values like 3.6666 for product_id 10.

Comment: You want to take an average over what? Over days, months? Can you be more specific about what your calculation should be? Currently avg(s.value) gives you a true average of the entries in your table, but what type of baseline is it that you want to average?

Comment: So every stock is supposed to stay unchanged until the next entry, but does not exist before the first entry? How do you unlist items?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The **special difficulty** here: you cannot just pick data points inside your time range, but have to consider the *latest* data point *before* the time range and the *earliest* data point *after* the time range additionally. This varies for every row and each data point may or may not exist. Requires a sophisticated query and makes it hard to use indexes.

You can use [**range types**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-range.html) and [**operators**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-range.html#RANGE-OPERATORS-TABLE) (Postgres **9.2+**) to simplify calculations:

```sql
WITH input(a,b) AS (SELECT '2013-01-01'::date   -- your time frame here
                         , '2013-01-15'::date)  -- inclusive borders
SELECT store_id, product_id
     , sum(upper(days) - lower(days))                    AS days_in_range
     , round(sum(value * (upper(days) - lower(days)))::numeric
                   / (SELECT b-a+1 FROM input), 2)       AS your_result
     , round(sum(value * (upper(days) - lower(days)))::numeric
                    / sum(upper(days) - lower(days)), 2) AS my_result
FROM (
   SELECT store_id, product_id, value, s.day_range * x.day_range AS days
   FROM  (
      SELECT store_id, product_id, value
           , daterange (day, lead(day, 1, CURRENT_DATE)
                OVER (PARTITION BY store_id, product_id ORDER BY day)) AS day_range
      FROM   stock
      ) s
   JOIN  (
      SELECT daterange(a, b+1) FROM input
      ) x(day_range) ON s.day_range && x.day_range
   ) sub
GROUP  BY 1, 2
ORDER  BY 1, 2;
```

Note, I use the column name `day` instead of `date`. I never use basic type names as column names.

In the subquery `sub` I fetch the day from the next row for each item with the window function `lead()`, using the built-in option to provide "today" as default where there is no next row.
With this I form a `daterange` and match it against the input with the [**overlap operator `&&`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-range.html#RANGE-OPERATORS-TABLE), computing the resulting date range with the [**intersection operator `*`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-range.html#RANGE-OPERATORS-TABLE).

All ranges here are with **exclusive** upper border. That's why I add one day to the input range. This way we can simply subtract `lower(range)` from `upper(range)` to get the number of days.

I assume that "yesterday" is the latest day with reliable data. "Today" can still change in a real life application. So I `CURRENT_DATE` as exclusive upper bound for open ranges.

I provide two results:

- `your_result` agrees with your displayed results.
  You divide by the number of days in your date range unconditionally. For instance, if an item is only listed for the last day, you get a very low (misleading!) "average".
- `my_result` computes the same or higher numbers.
  I divide by the *actual* number of days an item is listed. For instance, if an item is only listed for the last day, I return the listed value as average.

To make sense of the difference I added the number of days the item was listed: `days_in_range`

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/25X28bf_)
<sub>Old [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/4fc00/1)</sub>

### Index and performance

For this kind of data, old rows typically don't change. This would make an excellent case for a **materialized view**:

```sql
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW mv_stock AS
SELECT store_id, product_id, value
     , daterange (day, lead(day, 1, now()::date)
          OVER (PARTITION BY store_id, product_id ORDER BY day)) AS day_range
FROM   stock;
```

Then you can add a [GiST index which supports the relevant operator `&&`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html#RANGETYPES-INDEXING):

```
CREATE INDEX mv_stock_range_idx ON mv_stock USING gist (day_range);
```

In Postgres 9.6 or later possibly even a [covering index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-index-only-scans.html):

```
CREATE INDEX mv_stock_range_plus_idx ON mv_stock USING gist (day_range) INCLUDE (store_id, product_id, value);
```

#### Big test case

I ran a more realistic test with 200k rows. The query using the MV was ~ 6x as fast, which in turn was ~ 10x as fast as @Joop's query. (~ 50x in later test with Postgres 16.) Performance heavily depends on data distribution. An MV helps most with big tables and high frequency of entries. Also, if the table has additional columns not relevant to this query, the MV can be smaller. A question of cost vs. gain.

I've put all solutions posted so far (and adapted) in a big fiddle to play with:

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ijMbwgwk) with big test case
<sub>Old [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/91469/1)</sub>

Comment: Weighting the values of the gaps with DAYS_IN_RANGE was pretty slick

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter: the carthesian join on the calendar was never meant to be a speed deamon, but intended to show that simple cases of gaps-and-islands can be handled in different ways. For trivial cases (few thousands records) this is often fast enough, and easier to write/read/rewrite.

Comment: @joop: True. And I actually like your answer. (I have used similar techniques in more than one answer myself.) Just reporting the results from my test, as I am very interested in performance myself.

Answer (score 3):

This is rather quick&dirty: instead of doing the nasty interval arithmetic, just join to a calendar-table and sum them all.

```
WITH calendar(zdate) AS ( SELECT generate_series('2013-01-01'::date, '2013-01-15'::date, '1 day'::interval)::date )
SELECT st.store_id,st.product_id
        , SUM(st.zvalue) AS sval
        , COUNT(*) AS nval
        , (SUM(st.zvalue)::decimal(8,2) / COUNT(*) )::decimal(8,2) AS wval
FROM calendar
JOIN stocks st ON calendar.zdate >= st.zdate
        AND NOT EXISTS ( -- this calendar entry belongs to the next stocks entry 
                SELECT * FROM stocks nx
                WHERE nx.store_id = st.store_id AND nx.product_id = st.product_id
                AND nx.zdate > st.zdate AND nx.zdate <= calendar.zdate
        )
GROUP BY st.store_id,st.product_id
ORDER BY st.store_id,st.product_id
        ;
```

Comment: @ConradFrix: your sample data has one extra row. Also: I never use `date` as a column name. It sometimes works, at other times it may work differently.

Comment: I'm with you on not using keywords for column/object names, although I typically make my best effort to use the OP's names. You should also feel free to change the fiddle as you see fit. It makes a new URL each time you change the schema or sql.

Comment: I'm sorry; I refuse to use non-standard editing facilities. They cost too much time. For the web it is just cut&paste and get out ASAP. The fiddle does not allow easy screen-scraping so I avoid it as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is based on the implied idea that you're seeking the average over days, so each day counts as a new row. While this can be handled in other SQL engines in row form, this one was easier to implement by taking apart Average (Sum(value)/count(value)) and extrapolating it to number of days at that value. using your table format, and this goal, I came up with this solution ([SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/33656/1))

```
select store_id, product_id, CASE WHEN sum(nextdate-date) > 0 THEN sum(Value*(nextdate-date)) / sum(nextdate-date) END as Avg_Value
from (
  select *
      , (
        select value
        from stocks b
        where a.store_id = b.store_id
          and a.product_id = b.product_id
          and a.date >= b.date
        order by b.date
        limit 1
      )*1.0 "value"
      , coalesce((
        select date
        from stocks b
        where a.store_id = b.store_id
          and a.product_id = b.product_id
          and a.date < b.date
        order by b.date
        limit 1
      ),case when current_date > '2013-01-12' then '2013-01-12' else current_date end) nextdate
  from (
    select store_id, product_id, min(case when date < '2013-01-07' then '2013-01-07' else date end) date
    from stocks z
    where date < '2013-01-12'
    group by store_id, product_id
    ) a
  union all
  select store_id, product_id, date, value*1.0 "value"
    , coalesce((
      select date
      from stocks b
      where a.store_id = b.store_id
        and a.product_id = b.product_id
        and a.date < b.date
      order by b.date
      limit 1
    ),case when current_date > '2013-01-12' then '2013-01-12' else current_date end) nextdate
  from stocks a
  where a.date between '2013-01-07' and '2013-01-12'
) t
group by store_id, product_id
;
```

The query takes the first occurrence of each store/product before the start parameter (`'2013-01-07'`), and swaps in the parameter as the date if it's greater than the table's recorded date, selects the value for that early entry, and the date of the first change in the table after the start parameter, and keeps the next date constrained to the end parameter (`'2013-01-12'`). The second part of the union query grabs all changes between the two parameters, and the next change, or the current date, both constrained by the end parameter. Finally, the calculation is run on the results where values are multiplied by the date differences when they're summed, divided by the sum of days between the dates. Since all dates are constrained in the query, the average will be average over the exact window that are passed in as parameters.

Not being all that up on PostgreSQL, I advise that if you plan to implement this in a function, copying this query and replacing all instances of `'2013-01-07'` with your start parameter name, and all instances `'2013-01-12'` of with your end parameter name will give you the results your looking for for any given date window.

Edit: If you want an average over a different time unit, simply replace the two instances of `nextdate-date` with whatever date interval calculation you're looking for. `nextdate-date` returns number of days between the two.

Comment: PostgreSQL is more like SQL Server 2012 and Oracle than I think you realize.

Comment: I get `division by zero` in a bigger test case.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter, huh, you're right. included a case statement to mimic the behavior of avg() over 0 records.