# Reporting on a grouped average over a group of records

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

My goal is to generate a report showing the average occupancy of a garage (y-axis) at a given day of the week and/or time of day. My data model is as follows:

- Garage `has_many` Cars and Garage `has_many` Appointments, `through: :cars`
- Car `has_many` Appointments
- Appointment has fields such as:

  - picked_up_at (datetime)
  - returned_at (datetime)

Also, Garage has a field `capacity (integer)`, which is the maximum number of cars that will fit in the garage.

If I have a list of Appointments spanning the last 6 months, and I would like to generate a line-graph with the x-axis showing each day of the week, broken down into 4-hour intervals, and the y-axis showing the average % occupancy (# of cars in the garage / capacity) over the 6 month period for the given day/hour interval, how can I go about gathering this data to report on?

E.g. a car is `In` from the time of one Appointment's return until the next Appointment's pickup, and `Out` from the Appointment's pickup until it's `returned_at` time.

I am having a lot of trouble making the connection from these data points to the best way to meaningfully report on and present them to the end user.

I am using Rails 4.1 and Ruby 2.0.

Edit: SQL Fiddle - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a72fe/1

Comment: Your fiddle is for MySQL. You'll want to change that to Postgres to match your question: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/77901/1. Also, you neglected to mention possible NULL values in `returned_at` (I also adapted the schema to match your column names.)

Comment: So do you have your answer?

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter - sorry for the delay in selecting an answer, I've been out of the country, but I will be working to implement your solution and as soon as I do I will accept the answer. Thanks again

Answer (score 4):

This query would do it all (adapted to your added fiddle):

```
SELECT a.ts, g.*, round((a.ct * numeric '100') / g.capacity, 2) AS pct
FROM  (
   SELECT ts, c.garage_id, count(*) AS ct
   FROM   generate_series(timestamp '2015-06-01 00:00'  -- lower and
                        , timestamp '2015-12-01 00:00'  -- upper bound of range
                        , interval  '4h') ts
   JOIN   appointment a ON a.picked_up_at <= ts     -- incl. lower
                       AND (a.returned_at >  ts OR
                            a.returned_at IS NULL)  -- excl. upper bound
   JOIN   car c ON c.id = a.car_id
   GROUP  BY 1, 2
   ) a
JOIN   garage g ON g.id = a.garage_id
ORDER  BY 1, 2;
```

[**SQL Fiddle.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/77901/1)

If `returned_at IS NULL`, this query assumes that the car is still in use. So NULL shouldn't occur for other cases or you have an error in the calculation.

First, I build the time series with the convenient [`generate_series()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-srf.html#FUNCTIONS-SRF-SERIES) function.

Then join to appointments where the timestamp falls inside a booking.
I assume every appointment with including lower and excluding upper timestamp as it the widespread convention.

Aggregate and count before we join to garages (faster this way). Compare:

- [Aggregate a single column in query with many columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16018237/aggregate-a-single-column-in-query-with-many-columns/16023336#16023336)

Percent calculations in the outer `SELECT`.
I multiply the `bigint` number with `numeric` (or optionally `real` or `float`) to preserve fractional digits, which would be cut off in an integer division. Then I round to two fractional digits.

**Note** that this is not exactly the average percentage of each 4-hour period, but only the current percentage at each point in time, which is an approximation of the true average. You might start with an odd timestamp like '2015-06-01 01:17' so not to fall in between bookings that would probably turn over at full hours or something, which might increase the mean error of the approximation.

You can do an exact calculation for 4h periods, too, but that's more sophisticated. One simple technique would be to reduce the interval to 10 minutes or some granularity that's detailed enough to capture the full picture.

Related (with an example for exact calculation):

- [Calculate working hours between 2 dates in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1839319/calculate-working-hours-between-2-dates-in-postgresql/17282639#17282639)
- [Average stock history table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25247911/average-stock-history-table/25252274#25252274)

Comment: Thanks for the quick and detailed response! I will review/test this and report back!

Comment: When I copy your query into my fiddle, I get this error: `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'numeric '100') / g.capacity, 2) AS pct FROM ( SELECT ts, c.garage_id, count(' at line 1`, should that have worked directly as you had it written?

Comment: @jackerman09: Because *your*  fiddle  is for MySQL (which is simply wrong for a question tagged for Postgres). Try *my* fiddle, it works.