# SQL OVERLAPS how to include the dates of at the extremes?

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, overlap

How to include in an SQL OVERLAPS the start and the end date?

Like <= >=. How to?

Because it seeems to me that OVERLAPS check only the range in between, but for example:

Date 01 Jan 2001 - 05 Jan 2001 are already in database,

I choose the 5 Jan as the first date of the new range and it says to me that is good. Instead I want `OVERLAPS = true` because 5 Jan 2001 is already in the database and I cannot start the new range from 5 Jan but from 6 Jan.

How to include extreme dates in OVERLAPS?

Comment: From the [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/functions-datetime.html) : `Each time period is considered to represent the half-open interval start <= time < end, unless start and end are equal in which case it represents that single time instant. This means for instance that two time periods with only an endpoint in common do not overlap.`

Comment: @Marth, so a solution? Can you help me?

Comment: I would probably use @gordonlinoff 's solution. Another way (also excluding the "add 1 day" ~hack) would be to construct closed `daterange`s and then use the `&&` operator. However I do not have any benchmark for these solutions, but if you do do one, please share!

Comment: @Marth, I don't understand your `daterange's` solution. Can you explain it better?

Comment: just posted it as answer. Please ask if anything is still unclear.

Comment: This question needs a table definition and the exact query you tried (even if it's not working). The best solution may depend on your data types. And *always* your Postgres version. Closely related answer with detailed explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15305292/939860

Answer (score 3):

You could use closed `daterange`s (the `'[]'` argument) and the `&&` (overlap) operator :

```
SELECT daterange('2001-01-01', '2001-01-05', '[]') &&
       daterange('2001-01-05', '2001-01-10', '[]');
┌──────────┐
│ ?column? │
├──────────┤
│ t        │
└──────────┘
```

---

Note that using ranges also give you access to a lot of useful [operators](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/functions-range.html).

Comment: `&&` is even more proprietary than `OVERLAPS` and uses the same logic :-)

Comment: @dnoeth : Well, yeah, but you can closed instead of half-open. Though to be honest I would probably go with Gordon Linoff's solution anyway.

Comment: Of course you're right, I overlooked the `[]`. That's a nice extension, but the operator syntax is really cryptic....

Answer (score 1):

Interesting.  I don't use `overlaps` for two reasons.  The first is that it is only available in Postgres (and I don't like to get too used to constructs only available in one database).  The second is that simple equalities are sufficient.

Two intervals overlap when the first starts on or before the second ends *and* the first ends on or after the second starts.  Here is a schematic of the logic you want:

```
where first.start <= second.end and first.end >= second.start
```

Comment: But maybe OVERLAPS is more efficient if i'm using just and only PostfreSQL?

Comment: @JohnSam . . . That is possible.  If so, you can add/subtract one day from your ranges.

Comment: I think the solution of subtract date is like an hack and I wouldn't use it. I need a good solution. It'll be interesting to benchmark the efficiently from `OVERLAPS` and `<=` solution. How can I test it with a lot of seeds?

Comment: Worth noting that `OVERLAPS` is *standard* SQL.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter . . . That is good to note, and when other databases start supporting it, I will be more inclined to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Standard SQL's OVERLAP is based on a half-open period, i.e. the begin is included while the end is excluded.

This is the from the ISO 9075 document:

```
The result of the <overlaps predicate> is the result of the following expression:
( S1 > S2 AND NOT ( S1 >= T2 AND T1 >= T2 ) )
OR
( S2 > S1 AND NOT ( S2 >= T1 AND T2 >= T1 ) )
OR
( S1 = S2 AND ( T1 <> T2 OR T1 = T2 ) )
```

It's a bit strange for a human being, but only only as long as you deal with DATEs: 
*Monday* to *Wednesday* overlaps *Wednesday* to *Friday*, because one assumes it's the *end* of Wednesday for the end date but the *begin* for the start date.

But this changes when you switch to TIMESTAMPs:
*Monday morning* to *Wednesday noon* doesn't overlap *Wednesday noon* to *Friday evening*.

In fact it's much easier to work with half-open intervals because the begin of the next period is exactly the end of the previous period and you don't have to think about adding a day/second/milli-second.

I'm used to that for years for implementing temporal tables (slowly changing dimensions), which are Standard SQL now and implemented in Teradata, DB2 and the next release of SQL Server.

So you should consider changing your implementation :-) If you can't you can either add/subtract a day before using OVERLAPS or use Gordon's logic, do what's easier for you and don't care that much about efficiency. (I prefer the 1st because Teradata supports some nice functionality for periods which is hard to rewrite).

Comment: Or maybe I can subtract minutes from a date (or add, it's the same). Thanks.